# A nice group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, alternative-proof, cyclic-groups

Show that $$k(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\cong (\gcd(n,k)\mathbb{Z})/n\mathbb{Z}.$$

I want to see as many as possible proofs of this nice fact.

Comment: What $k(\mathbb Z_n)$ means?

Comment: Have you come up with any proofs yourself?

Answer (score 2):

We have $k\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}=\gcd(n,k)\mathbb{Z}$, by the Euclidean algorithm, and taking the quotient by $n\mathbb{Z}$ gives the result.

Comment: How exactly do you conclude? Do you use the second isomorphism theorem?